What are the cellPadding values in Azure Data Studio
I’m trying to get used to Azure Data Studio after using SSMS for some time, and, so far, I think its interface is very unfinished.
I want to change the cell padding, which I didn’t like to begin with, but gets worse if I change the font size.
The settings helpfully tells you to edit it in the settings.json file. OK, but the only information there is something like:
"resultsGrid.cellPadding": [
    2,
    8,
    4
],

By experimentation I gather that:

The first figure is the top padding
The second figure is the left padding
You really need to also set resultsGrid.rowHeight to finish the job

I suppose the numbers are in pixels, and that they’re not relative but absolute: you need to change them again if you change the font size.
What is the meaning of the third figure? I’ve changed it something large, as well as to 0 and I can’t see any difference.
I’m trying it out on Windows 10. I’ve also tried it out on the Mac.

From what I can tell, the third number adjusts minimum gridline top padding on the first row.  Not the height of the entire row mind, just the the line portion
For example, if I use the following settings:
"resultsGrid.cellPadding": [1,5,60],
"resultsGrid.rowHeight": 20

Then the first gridline will occur after the top three rows.

